# Customize number display on dial pad on Android 4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is it possible to customize how numbers are displayed when dialing a number?
For example:
Instead of grouping them with spaces like `555 123 123`, I'd like it to have no grouping: `555123123`.

On 2.3 you could do that from the locale, US had spaces and UK did not.
On 4.1 it seems that both US and UK have the same spaces.

Can it be changed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the date, there is no functionality to disable this feature. Actually this was implemented to make it easier for the user to recognize and remeber the number easily.

I did some search and found out that other people [have the same problem](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1764021) as well.

What I suggest is to move on to a custom dialer app [which suit you the best](http://www.techshout.com/features/2012/24/best-android-dialer-apps/), if this grouping feature really annoys you.

Comment: Thank you, Sid. Awesome answer. I know grouping is supposed to help, but they way it groups digits is bad for how numbers are formed where I live.